# Order of printing exceptions output in java

Tags: java, exception

I came a cross an interesting undefined behavior in java exception handling/printing order

I could not find the answer for this and would like to ask the experts here for their view on the phenomenon and share their understanding about it

this is the code I am running:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainClass {
public static void main (String[] args) { 
    MainClass mc = new MainClass();
    try {
        mc.func3();
    } catch (MyException2 e) {
        System.out.println("LOOK AT TRACE !!");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mc.func4();
}

public void func3() throws MyException2 {
    throw new MyException2();
}

public void func4() {
    throw new MyException1();
}
}

class MyException1 extends RuntimeException {
public MyException1() {
    System.out.println("MyException1 created! inherits from  RuntimeException!");
}
}

class MyException2 extends IOException {
public MyException2() {
    System.out.println("MyException2 created! inherits from IOException!");
}
}
```

I expected to have the same output as I run MainClass.main over and over, but in reality I get different order of outputs. The behavior seems random, except for exception2 is always the first to be created.

for example:

```
output1:

MyException2 created! inherits from IOException!
LOOK AT TRACE !!
MyException1 created! inherits from  RuntimeException!exercises.ex3.MyException2

at exercises.ex3.MainClass.func3(MainClass.java:19)
at exercises.ex3.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:9)
Exception in thread "main" exercises.ex3.MyException1
at exercises.ex3.MainClass.func4(MainClass.java:23)
at exercises.ex3.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:15)

output2:

MyException2 created! inherits from IOException!
LOOK AT TRACE !!
exercises.ex3.MyException2
    at exercises.ex3.MainClass.func3(MainClass.java:19)
    at exercises.ex3.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:9)
MyException1 created! inherits from RuntimeException!
Exception in thread "main" exercises.ex3.MyException1
    at exercises.ex3.MainClass.func4(MainClass.java:23)
    at exercises.ex3.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:15)

output3:

MyException2 created! inherits from IOException!
LOOK AT TRACE !!
exercises.ex3.MyException2
    at exercises.ex3.MainClass.func3(MainClass.java:19)
    at exercises.ex3.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:9)
Exception in thread "main" exercises.ex3.MyException1
    at exercises.ex3.MainClass.func4(MainClass.java:23)
    at exercises.ex3.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:15)
MyException1 created! inherits from RuntimeException!
```

Comment: Behavior might be related to the fact `printStackTrace()` prints to `System.err` while your other messages are printed to `System.out`.

Comment: Hi Slaw, thank you very much. Could you elaborate a little bit more on the topic? what does it mean that one is printing to system.err and the other to system.out? why can't the order be stable because of this? Thanks again !

Comment: 2 streams in one console. Underlying implementation will decide about multiplexing